# How to access the attribute of a child element in java using jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

Let's assume the HTML file is of the format,

```
<div>
   <a href"something" title"something"></a>
</div>
```

I've used jsoup to get all the div tags, I just want to access the child element of div. I used the `.html()` method, but it returns a string, and I can't further manipulate it using the methods under Elements.

Comment: @Akash did one of these answers solve your problem?

Comment: yes, thank you so much(sorry for the late reply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the div's as Elements, use CSS selectors to find the child element, then attr(String) to access the attributes.

```
Elements divs = doc.select("div");
for (Element div : divs)
    String href = div.select("a").first().attr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this example

```
  String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element link = doc.select("a").first();

        String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
        String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
        String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

        String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
            // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
        String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```